# I'm creating a PDF in Prawn and I'm trying to use :absolute_top_left and :absolute_top_right but they both send it to the top left

Tags: ruby, prawn

This is what I have so far

```
Prawn::Document.generate(location) do |pdf|    

  pdf.text location1, :absolute_top_left => true
  pdf.text location2, :absolute_top_left => true
  pdf.text location3, :absolute_top_left => true
    
  pdf.text location4, :absolute_top_right => true
  pdf.text location5, :absolute_top_right => true
  pdf.text location6, :absolute_top_right => true

end
```

For some reason, it puts everything to the left, the ones with `:absolute_top_right` are on top, but going left instead of right, am I doing this wrong?

Comment: What would lead you to believe these are options? https://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.3.0/Prawn/Text.html#text-instance_method does not show them as options and the references I can find are that these are bounding box methods that return the point within the bounding box

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a bounding box or the `:at` keyword, `:absolute_top_left` is not an option that I can find anywhere.

See *'text/positioned_text.rb'* in https://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf

```
Prawn::Document.generate(location) do |pdf|    
  pdf.text location1
  pdf.move_down 10
    
  pdf.text_box location4, :at [300, 100]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#absolute_top_left` method and the other, similarly named methods are methods on the bounding box objects of Prawn. They return the absolute coordinates instead of the relative coordinates.

For example, if you start an empty document, the `#top_left` would return `(0, yyy)` where `yyy` is the height of the margin box. The `#absolute_top_left` method would return `(xxx, yyy + zzz)` where `xxx` is the margin on the left and `zzz` is the margin at the bottom.